# VBA Excel Fails to run because of Compile Error: Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

When I go to run the VBA code it gives me an error of "Compile Error: Type Mismatch". It doesn't give an error code like it previously has.

It is being used to work on this data. The data on the left is a table that I am running against the values in Row J and assigning the ID in Row M

[Image of Excel][1]

```
Sub Cat()
    Dim i As String
    Dim x As String

    For i = 1 To 113
        For x = 1 To 13
            If Sheet1.Cells("B", i).Value = Sheet1.Cells("J", x) Then
                Sheet1.Cells("A", i).Value = Sheet1.Cells("M", x)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I am expecting IDs of Row A to be inserted where B and M equal as per the for loops

Comment: `For i = 1 To 113`: if you are going to use `i` as numbers, don't `dim` it as a `string`. Use `Dim i as long` instead. Same with `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Multiple Type Mismatch

Remember: You can use e.g. `Cells(i, "B")` or `Range("B" & i)` for a one-cell range.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Cat()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long

    For i = 1 To 113
        For x = 1 To 13
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, "J") Then
                Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, "M")
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("B" & i)` is objectively a better idea than parameterizing `Cells` with a string argument for the column though. Remember that `Cells` has no parameters, it just returns a `Range` object; the parameters go against the hidden `Item` property, through a default member call. Quite roundabout IMO.

Comment: Just putting emphasis on the use of Option Explicit...string variables used within a counting loop would have been instantly flagged with a compile.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious `i As String` being illegally used as an integer value for loop-counting (should be declared `As Long`), you are inverting the `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` arguments of an implicit `Range.[_Default]` member call:

[image]

```
Sheet1.Cells("B", i).Value
```

`"B"` isn't a valid *RowIndex* value.

Rule of thumb, avoid `Range.Cells` when you have a string for a column; use it when you have a row *index* and a column *index*, i.e. numeric values for row & column.

When you have a column heading string such as `"B"`, use the `Range` property and concatenate the cell address, e.g. `Sheet1.Range("B" & i)`.